# Implementing a mailing list: avoid infinite mailing list TO field loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, mailgun

I'm building a service that has an option of allowing users to send emails to a dynamically created mailing lists created by the service.

For example, a user could send:

```
From: user1 <user1@example.com>
To: list-a <list1@service.com>
Body: ....
```

My service then intercepts the email (using [Mailgun routes](http://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#routes)) and sends it to the users in the list:

```
From: user1 <user1@example.com>
BCC: user2 <user2@example.com>, user3 <user3@example.com>
Body: ....
```

However I would like to have the TO field set to list1@service.com, but then the result is an infinite mailing loop.

How can I avoid the infinite mailing loop?

Answer (score 1):

In your mailer function, after calling `mail = mail(to: mailing_list_email, from: from, subject: subject)` use `message.smtp_envelope_to = real_to_email` to deliver the message to each subscriber to the subscription list.
Notice that some mailing services do not allow different to field in the envelope.
Also make sure you're using SMTP as the backend for mail delivery.